# Modifying tables on Button Click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I have two splitpanes inside the main window wherein i have two tables on either side. I have left and right arrow buttons just next to the divider, again each on either side of it.

I want that, when i click one of the cells on the left table, the entire row should be selected and then on the right arrow button's click, the selected row be added to the table on the right splitpane and be highlighted indicating the addition of a new row to the table.

Also i want viceversa to be possible, like transferring a row from table in right splitpane to table in left splitpane.

I am relatively new to GUI in java.

The only code that i have is this...

```
    JPanel jsp1 = new JPanel();
    jsp1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(460,600));
    jsp1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JPanel jsp2 = new JPanel();
    jsp2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    jsp1.setLayout(null);
    jsp2.setLayout(null);

    JLabel j1 = new JLabel("Left Splitpane");
    j1.setBounds(150,10,100,20);

    JLabel j2 = new JLabel("Right Splitpane");
    j2.setBounds(200,10,100,20);

    jsp1.add(j1);
    jsp2.add(j2);

    JButton left = new JButton ();
    left.setBorderPainted(false);
    left.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton right = new JButton ();
    right.setBorderPainted(false);
    right.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    left.add(new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.WEST));
    right.add(new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.EAST));

    left.setBounds(397, 220, 80, 45);
    right.setBounds(-15, 220, 80, 45);

    jsp1.add(left);
    jsp2.add(right);

    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, 
            true, jsp1, jsp2);

    splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(false);
    getContentPane().add(splitPane);

    Object [] columns = {"Name", "Number", "City"};
    Object [][] data = {{"Adam", 1, "London"},{"Charlie", 3, "New York"},{"Phil", 5, "Madrid"},{"Megan", 2, "Amstredam"},
            {"Wayne",11, "Paris"},{"Mary", 8, "Venice"},{"Jones", 7, "Sydney"},};

    JTable mytable = new JTable(data,columns);
    mytable.setRowHeight(60);
    JTable mynewtable = new JTable(data,columns);
    mynewtable.setRowHeight(60);
    mynewtable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true); 

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(mytable);
    scroll.setBounds(30,80,350,455);
    JScrollPane scrollone = new JScrollPane(mynewtable);
    scrollone.setBounds(80,80,350,455);

    jsp1.add(scroll);
    jsp2.add(scrollone);
```

Comment: Null layouts == bad idea

Answer (score 1):

Use:

- [`JTable#setRowSelectionAllowed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionAllowed(boolean)) to allow the row to be highlighted when selected
- Add `ActionListener`s to your buttons so you know when they are triggered.  See [How to write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- By default, `JTable` is backed by a `DefaultTableModel`.  You can use [`DefaultTableModel#getDataVector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getDataVector()) to get the row data buffer and [`JTable.addRow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow(java.util.Vector)) to move data between the tables.

You'll also want to take a look at [Laying out components within a container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout) to fix issues with your layout

## Updated with example

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTable left;
        private JTable right;

        public TestPane() {
            Object[] columns = {"Name", "Number", "City"};
            Object[][] data = {{"Adam", 1, "London"}, {"Charlie", 3, "New York"}, {"Phil", 5, "Madrid"}, {"Megan", 2, "Amstredam"},
            {"Wayne", 11, "Paris"}, {"Mary", 8, "Venice"}, {"Jones", 7, "Sydney"},};

            DefaultTableModel leftModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
            DefaultTableModel rightModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);

            left = new JTable(leftModel);
            right = new JTable(rightModel);

            JButton moveRight = new JButton("-->");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            add(new JScrollPane(left), gbc);
            gbc.gridx += 2;
            add(new JScrollPane(right), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            add(moveRight, gbc);

            moveRight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int index = left.getSelectedRow();
                    if (index != -1) {
                        index = left.convertRowIndexToModel(index);
                        DefaultTableModel leftModel = (DefaultTableModel) left.getModel();
                        DefaultTableModel rightModel = (DefaultTableModel) right.getModel();

                        Vector rowData = (Vector) leftModel.getDataVector().get(index);
                        leftModel.removeRow(index);
                        rightModel.addRow(rowData);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi i have updated my code, on using tablemodel.(getSelectedRow), i am able to remove it from one of the tables. However i am not able to add the removed row into second table.  I Also got the button ActionListner working. So its now only about how to use addrow with getSelectedRow method

Comment: In what form is the row data?  `DefaultTableModel` has a `addRow` method

Comment: The row data is like this 
Object [] [] data = {{"London", 2,"venue1}, {"NeyYork",3,"venue3"}}

Comment: right.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {
          try{
           tabletable.removeRow(mytable.getSelectedRow());
          }

I have this in the actionlistener method....i m able to remove a selected row from tabletable TableModel. Now i have another TableModel called tablemynewtable where this row has to be added.

Comment: You need to pull the value from the `JTable` first, before you remove it.  You then need to add this value to the second table

Comment: How do i pull the value of the selectedrow.

Comment: You have two choices, you can either use `JTable#getValueAt` and extract the value for each column of a given row, then (after calling `addRow`), feed it back into the second table using `JTable#setValueAt`, not the prettiest, but it works, or you can use the `DefaultTableModel#getDataVector`, which returns a `Vector` of `Vector`s, each element representing a given row, and simply use `JTable#addRow` (there's two versions of `addRow`, one takes a `Object[]` and one takes `Vector`)

Comment: could please share some code for better understanding....i did not understand the part where u said after calling addrow , feed it back to second table using setvalueat